# Horizontal nav keeps displaying vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm working through a [PSD to HTML5/CSS3](https://www.udemy.com/build-beautiful-html5-website/#/) course on Udemy, and my results aren't rendering like those shown in the screencast. I'd post comparison screenshots if SO didn't require a rep of 10, but basically the author's version renders the list items horizontally, without bullets, while mine keep rendering vertically, with bullets.

#### HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container clearfix">
        <a href="/" title="Return to Home" id="logo">
          <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- end container -->
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS:

```
/* Navigation Styling */

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}
nav ui li {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    border-left: solid 1px #333;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

I've tried switching `display` in `header nav ul li a` to `inline`, which would seem to be more logical for a horizontal list, but that doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: `nav ui li` should be `nav ul li`.

Comment: Change as @Oriol states [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1jsf044/1/)

Comment: So have you put more than 4 hours into this project as the sales pitch proclaims?

Comment: Oriol has the correct answer... this is a syntax error.

Comment: @Oriol: What an eagle eye. That did the trick. Until SO allows comments to be accepted as answers, I'll have to settle for thanking you.

Comment: @ben.kaminski: It's four hour of instruction time. Needless to say, instruction time and learning time are somewhat different :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your **css**, just replace `nav ui li` by `nav ul li`.